# How to map table to different probabilities of data resuts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, stored-procedures, data-structures

If i have table like this :

> Shifts

```
Id  name  desc

1   W_W   Work-Work
2   W-E   Work-WeekEnd
3   E-W   WeekEnd-Work
4   E-E   WeekEnd-WeekEnd
```

---

**NOTE :**`day_type =3` means `week_end` and any other value means `work_day`
And i have a data result consists of two records one for the day and the other for tomorrow day like this :

If the input :`5-20-2015`

> Result Set 1:

```
day-type   dayDate
   1       5-20-2015
   1       5-21-2015
```

---

If the input : `5-21-2015`

> Result Set 2:

```
day-type   dayDate
   1       5-21-2015
   3       5-22-2015
```

and so on( four possibilities )
I want to get the result like this:

> for the first case :

```
day-type   dayDate          shift_id
   1       5-20-2015           1
   1       5-21-2015           -
```

---

> for the second case

```
day-type   dayDate          shift_id
   1       5-21-2015           2
   3       5-22-2015           -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second test case is wrong, it should also yield a shift_id of 1 because 5-21-2015 and 5-22-205 are both work days. At least in my universe. BTW your SHIFTS table is unnecessary for this answer. Alter the value of `@InputDate` to test different scenarios.

```
DECLARE @InputDate DATETIME
DECLARE @NextDate DATETIME
DECLARE @day_type1 INT
DECLARE @day_type2 INT

SET @InputDate = '20150522'
SET @NextDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @InputDate)
SELECT @day_type1 = CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DATENAME(weekday, @InputDate), 1, 1) = 'S' THEN 3 ELSE 1 END
SELECT @day_type2 = CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DATENAME(weekday, @NextDate),  1, 1) = 'S' THEN 3 ELSE 1 END

SELECT
  @day_type1 AS [day-type],
  @InputDate AS [dayDate],
  CASE 
    WHEN @day_type1 <> 3 AND @day_type2 <> 3 THEN '1'
    WHEN @day_type1 <> 3 AND @day_type2 =  3 THEN '2'
    WHEN @day_type1 =  3 AND @day_type2 <> 3 THEN '3'
    WHEN @day_type1 =  3 AND @day_type2 =  3 THEN '4'
  END AS [shift_id]
UNION ALL
SELECT
  @day_type2 AS [day-type],
  @NextDate  AS [dayDate],
  '-'
```

Comment: please look to the note `day_type =3 means week_end and any other value means work_day` this's my business rule .it could be different in your university .